# how to configure http adapter for physic device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Good days 
Please i am working with mobilefirst in one project which needs http adapter.
My adapter give a good answers when in run it in to mobilefirst server,but when i create an android environement and deside to run the same project in my physic android device (my android phone),this return error.
I try to get solution without reponse please help me thank you.

this is the adapter xml file :

```html
<wl:adapter name="RSSFeed"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
 xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

 <displayName>RSSFeed</displayName>
 <description>RSSFeed</description>
 <connectivity>
  <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <domain>www.ibm.com</domain>
   <port>80</port>
   <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
   <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
   <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
   <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
   <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
   <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
   -->  
  </connectionPolicy>
 </connectivity>

 <procedure name="getFeeds"/>
<procedure name="getFeedsFiltered"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

this is the error message :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzTKm.png)

this is complete error message :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEQqY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would've been easier had you provide basic information such as:

1. The error message...
2. The adapter XML file

Since you did not provide anything, here are some basic debugging items you should check for:

1. Make sure that in the adapter XML you are point in the `host` property to an actual IP address of the server the adapter should connect to. i.e **not** `localhost`
2. Make sure the device and the MobileFirst Server are **connected to the same network**
3. Print the error you receive in the client once the adapter request fails, and act upon it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1212_paris/1212_paris.html